# WPF Set PasswordBox from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `PasswordBox`, but if the user enters in too many characters, or enters a character they shouldn't have, or some other third thing, I need that change to act as if it never happened. e.g.: Max length is 5, but after entering 5 characters, the user enters a 6th. I want to remove that 6th character.

I've been looking for a couple hours now, but the closest thing I found was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747195/put-securestring-into-passwordbox). First line of that answer is, *"You can't."* **If that's the way things are, so be it.** However, to me, it feels like there has to be some way to do it.

I've tried a number of ways, but to no avail. `PasswordBox` doesn't have an `Undo` method like TextBox. Tried keeping a `DependencyProperty`, and using the OnDPChanged, reset the DP given the `e.OldValue`, but that is separate from the PasswordBox. I even thought to keep an `m_oldPassword` variable, but as the linked post says, *"You can't."*.

Theoretically, I could do something along the lines of `MyPasswordBox.Password = MyPasswordBox.Password.SubString(0, passLen - 1);` but 1, I don't want to expose the normal string for security reasons, 2, it wouldn't always be the last character that would be the problem, the user could have entered something in the middle.

**Official Question:** How do I reset a `PasswordBox` using a `SecureString` in my codebehind?
(Note: I don't really have any code to show, cause most/all of this is theoretical at the moment)

Comment: why do you need that and nobody else needs?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: i mean if others are not complaining about the control why do you? if you want a special control then create your own customer control.

Comment: I'm not complaining about it, I'm asking a question about how to work with it, or work around it.

Comment: Why you do not use MVVM?

Comment: I am using MVVM (at least in some cases), but if anything, that just makes dealing with a PasswordBox harder (in my limited experience)

Answer (score 0):

PasswordBox supports a MaxLength property to limit characters and a KeyDown event where you can setup rules in the code behind.

XAML

```
    <PasswordBox MaxLength="5" KeyDown="PasswordBox_KeyDown"/>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PasswordBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Put your rules here - Example rejects the period key
        if (e.Key == Key.OemPeriod)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Lastly, while you can't set the SecurePassword property directly, you can set the  Password property. I understand that you don't want to have the password as plain text in the application. So use an encrypted value and write logic to decrypt the value and assign it to the Password property.

```
    private void ResetButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox.Clear();
        PasswordBox.Password = DecryptSavedPassword(_encryptedPassword);
    }
```

Comment: That might help, I'll see what I can do with that. Thanks!

Comment: The .Password property setter takes an unencrypted String. If you decrypt the string only to use the setter, you might want to take a look at the answer I added that allows you to skip this step and lets you use a SecureString directly. (It uses reflection to get access to the private method called internally from the .Password setter that takes a SecureString instead of a String)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set/overwrite the password (other than just clearing it), I added an answer to the question you linked in the OP that shows how to set the Password property using a SecureString without the need to decrypt it to a String first. It uses reflection to either invoke the private SetSecurePassword() (which is called from the PasswordBox.Password setter) from a MethodInfo or compile and cache a delegate that will do this. ( for more detail see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66918246/2240196 )